# Can't make the items smaller with css grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, grid

I saw this CSS grid menu and I tried to modify it so that the items became smaller without having whitespace but I didn't succeed, do someone knows how to do it?

```css
nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
  
  a {
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">Home</a>
  <a href="">About</a>
  <a href="">Work</a>
  <a href="">Blog</a>
  <a href="">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try removing `grid-gap`?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "smaller" on x or y? You can try this maybe:

```css
nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
  grid-gap: 0px;
}
  
  a {
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">Home</a>
  <a href="">About</a>
  <a href="">Work</a>
  <a href="">Blog</a>
  <a href="">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `grid-gap:` to `0px;`

```css
nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
  grid-gap: 0px;
}

a {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">Home</a>
  <a href="">About</a>
  <a href="">Work</a>
  <a href="">Blog</a>
  <a href="">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

Better use Inline-block

```css
nav {
  display: inline-block;
}
  
  a {
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">Home</a>
  <a href="">About</a>
  <a href="">Work</a>
  <a href="">Blog</a>
  <a href="">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks, but is there a way to do the same thing without inline-block and float? just the grid

Comment: yes , try increasing `grid-template-columns` value 5 to 10 or so .